# Cannot redirect to an html after Shiny app disconnects

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I tried to redirect to an html page after Shiny app disconnects. I was able to find code [here](https://www.listendata.com/2021/03/show-game-when-shiny-disconnects.html) but it does not seem to work with ShinyDashboard. Not familiar with JavaScript so any help is appreciated!

Below is a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <-  dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(),

  dashboardSidebar(),

  dashboardBody(

  tags$script("

$(function() {$(document).on('shiny:disconnected shiny:error', function(event) {

    $('.container-fluid').load('./test.html');

  }) });

  "),

  actionButton("disconnect", "Disconnect the app")

  )

  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$disconnect, {

    session$close()

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```